# Estimating costing for entities on Azure VMs

Tags: hosting, azure, web-hosting, cloud

We are looking of moving our hosting solution over to Azure (we are a microsoft dev house so it makes sense). It just seems difficult to estimate costing for our hosting solution.

To give a simple rundown of our scenario. Our application is a simple asp.net frontend that backs onto an SQL Server database. We have a two tier setup on a VPS provider with 1 VM for the web box and 1 VM for the SQL box. When a customer comes onto our hosting solution they get a web application setup in IIS on the web box and a database connected on the sql box which talk to each other and the user is provided a web link to use (multi tenant setup isnt in the pipeline at this point). Currently we pay a one of monthly cost to the VPS provider and that covers everything.

Now moving to azure when we are looking at more of pay for what we use setup this changes the game a bit. What im wanting to do is to add a test company to the azure setup (we have a proof of concept copy in azure now) and simulate a days usage through it and than want to check the costs that it racks up on our account. Than create another test company and simulate a days usage and see what costs come from that. I was thinking once we've got so many test companies on the box we could than check the costs and average out that across the amount of companies and give us an estimate of how much an average company will cost us per day. Let me know if I'm being silly at this point? I would think this kind of cost forecasting would be pretty common.

The problem is that the only thing we seem to be able to do is check our account every morning and see what the cost was for the previous day, it seems very difficult if not impossible to drill down more costs. We can see each thing that we use on our account page (storage, cpu, input output) but it's hard to tie these back to actual daily costs.

Can anybody give advice on achieving what we are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the [VM Pricing Calculator](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/calculator/virtual-machines/)?  As long as you know roughly what your usage looks like in terms of bandwidth and storage then I'd think you could get a fairly accurate number from it.